# Loading multiple parquet files iteratively using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, parquet, pyspark

I looked for similar examples, but all of them had a specific string in the paths with numbers in the end and hence were able to perform a for loop iteratively. 
My scenario is as follows:
I have multiple parquet files in multiple partitions with the path as something like:
`s3a://path/idate=2019-09-16/part-{some random hex key1}.snappy.parquet
s3a://path/idate=2019-09-16/part-{some random hex key2}.snappy.parquet
etc...`.
The `{some random hex key}` is obviously not predictable and hence I cannot create a rule in iterative code definition. 
I would like to have a for loop for example like:

```
files="s3a://path/idate=2019-09-16/" 
for i in files
block{i}=spark.read.parquet(i)
```

where `block{i}` are `block1`, `block2` etc. and  are the iterative dataframes that would get created from `s3a://path/idate=2019-09-16/part-{some random hex **key1,2, etc**..}.snappy.parquet`

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read all the files in `files="s3a://path/idate=2019-09-16/"` using
`df = spark.read.parquet(files)`.

Comment: Thank you! That works. However, how would I store it in an iterative dataframe?
For example, 
`df[i]=spark.read.parquet(files)` 
I was thinking about writing it to seperate parquet files using iterative strings in the names and then call them back, but that seems ineffecient and defeats the purpose of doing it all in the kernel.
Any advice?

Comment: @thentangler You can directly read all the files at once and apply transformations on the `df` and write it using `df.write`. Provide some more context here and open a new question as it is unrelated. And please accept the answer if it solved your original query.